# Offset points in QGIS using attribute values for Bearing and Distance?

Tags: qgis, point, offset, data-collection

Background: I am working with a biodiversity researcher who will be collecting field data on frogs in Peru over the summer. Because of the dense canopy at the field site observations are taken by collecting a set of reference GPS coordinates, then using a small laser rangefinder and compass to find distances and bearings to frog observations from each reference spot. At the end of each day the researchers would like be able to plot a map of the observations based on the data they are collecting. The researchers are primarily using QGIS for their map work.

Question: Is there a workflow in QGIS that can take a set of XY coordinates (or point shapefile) and plot or transform them based on offset values from the original XY in bearings and distance?

[image: example data table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. I bet QGIS has a neat method or tool to do this but
I don't know it, so I did it manually.

I assumed the distance is given in meters...

1. First convert the data into a local projection (so coordinates are in meters):

- import the CSV (WGS84)
- export/reload the layer in central Peruvian projection (EPSG:24892)

2. Then add and calculate the new coordinates:

- add new attributes for the calculated frog locations (say xcoord and ycoord)
- in the field calculator calculate these final coordinates for each point:

> "xcoord" = x($geometry) +  "Distance" * sin(radians(Bearing))
>
> "ycoord" = y($geometry) +  "Distance" * cos(radians(Bearing))

3. Use the new coordinates:

- save the layer as CSV
- load the CSV using the xcoord and ycoord attributes as coordinates

This will give you the final locations. For the first four observations:

[image]

Ugly, but it works.

Comment: Thanks! I actually found a different but similar approach using the QGIS Geometry by Expression tool. If the data are projected to the local CRS (in meters) this is the expression for the tool: project (($geometry), "Distance", radians (“Bearing"))    Basically the same process but in app.

Comment: @David M: Ah, Yes. Much easier and cleaner. Thanks for the feedback...